# stack applet not getting sign in

Tags: bug, stackapps

I am facing problem during running of Stack Applet. How can I sign in? Moreover when I click on presences it comes up with localhost error . Here is the picture

[image]

As it can be seen, the Applet is showing `no accounts`  even though I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of StackApplet and I can verify that the problem you are experiencing is due to a small bug that has since been fixed but hasn't made its way into the latest build for Windows.

I will try to build the Windows installer again later and let you know when that is complete.

Comment: Nice to hear from author . I will be waiting for it .

Comment: @umar: [Here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe) it is. I haven't had time to get it into Launchpad yet, but you can try it out and see if it works.